# javascript higher order functions ; "this" parameters vs external "self" variable

Tags: javascript

When using higher order function of the Array API in javascript (forEach, map, filter, etc.)
there are 2 means to pass "this" variable :

```
myArray.forEach(function(value) {
    this.aContextualFunction();
}, this);
```

Or

```
var self = this;
myArray.forEach(function(value) {
    self.aContextualFunction();
});
```

Which one is the better ? 
What are the pros and cons ?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TkZgX/

Comment: Are you sure they both do the same thing? Can you show us the context and what you're trying to do?

Comment: In second, self is not inside foreach. its not same like first one. and if you define self inside, that will make it exactly similar to the first block.

Comment: @Dev they are the same, since first one injects `this` as `this` to forEach

Comment: This jsFiddle prove that we can do the same things with 2 style : http://jsfiddle.net/TkZgX/

Comment: I always prefer the first one. pro: no extra var declaration, con: maybe confusion as seen in this comments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using higher order functions I prefer my functions not to make any assumptions about the callbacks it receives as arguments. In general, the more loosely coupled the code the better.

For example, say I write a higher order function for `forEach`:

```
function forEach(array, callback, that) { // that is optional
    var length = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        callback.call(that, array[i], i); // pass the value and the index
}
```

Now say I want to use it:

```
Array.prototype.double = function () {
    forEach(this, function (value, index) {
        this[index] = 2 * value;
    });                                     // oops, I forgot that
};

var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.double();
```

The above code will cause variables to leak into the global scope. Not a good thing. See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dad4/

What's the alternative? Remove the optional third parameter and use closures:

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    var length = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        callback(array[i], i);
}
```

Not only is the code smaller, but there won't be any accidental global leaks (unless you use `this` instead of the external `that` like an idiot). Let's see an example:

```
Array.prototype.double = function () {
    var that = this;

    forEach(this, function (value, index) {
        that[index] = 2 * value;
    });
};

var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.double();
```

The demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dad4/1/

Hmmm... that doesn't seem very enticing - I don't want to create a new variable. May we do something better? Yes, we sure can. This is the method I prefer (we still use the second `forEach` function):

```
Array.prototype.double = function () {
    forEach(this, function (value, index) {
        this[index] = 2 * value;
    }.bind(this));
};

var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.double();
```

The demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dad4/2/

Wow, isn't this better? We combined both methods one and two. Advantages:

1. The `forEach` function doesn't assume anything. The code is more loosely coupled.
2. We don't need an external variable like `that`. No closures needed.
3. There's no confusion as to what's happening.

We can do this because the anonymous function passed to `forEach` is a function expression. So we just append `.bind(this)` to it and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

I always prefer the first one.

pro: no extra var declaration

con: maybe confusion as seen in the comments on this question..